# Convert FOL clauses to PROLOG

Tags: prolog, first-order-logic

I am very new to PROLOG so it might be a very trivial question, but I absolutely have no
idea how to solve it.
There are 4 sentences I need to formulate into PROLOG code:

> - All hounds howl at night.
> - Anyone who has any cats will not have any mice.
> - Light sleepers do not have anything which howls at night.
> - John has either a cat or a hound.

I convert sentences to well-formed formula in first-order predicate calculus like that

```
- ∀x (HOUND(x) → HOWL(x))

- ∀x ∀y (HAVE(x,y) ∧ CAT (y) → ¬∃z (HAVE(x,z) ∧ MOUSE (z)))

- ∀x (Light_Sleeper(x) → ¬∃y (HAVE (x,y) ∧ HOWL(y)))

- ∃x (HAVE (John,x) ∧ (CAT(x) ∨ HOUND(x)))
```

Now I don't know how to write them in Prolog.
Also, how can I make query on them?

Comment: The first clause is already a Horn clause, you can directly translate it.

Comment: Instead of using predicates to represent a cat / mouse / etc. you could use a constant. The second clause would become `∀x ( Have(x,cat) → ¬ Have(x, mouse) )`, but it is still not a Horn clause. Instead of defining a rule, it could be expressed as a query `∀x ¬( Have(x,cat) ∧ Have(x, mouse) )` but that needs negation. Since Prolog only implements [negation as failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure), the translation is only correct as long as `Have(x,y)` has only finitely many solutions.

Comment: The phrasing of the fourth clause suggests that John has a cat or a dog, but not both. If so, then you would need to make this explicit.

Answer (score 1):

> - All hounds howl at night.

```
hound(marshall).
hound(rubble).
howls_at_night(X) :-
    hound(X).

%% ?- howls_at_night(everest).
%% false.

%% ?- howls_at_night(rubble).
%% true.

%% ?- howls_at_night(Name).
%% Name = marshall
%% Name = rubble.
```

> - Anyone who has any cats will not have any mice.

```
cat(tom).
mice(jerry).
has(mammy, tom).
wont_have_mice(X) :- has(X, Y), cat(Y).
may_have_mice(X) :- has(X, Y) -> \+ cat(Y) ; true.

%% ?- may_have_mice(john).
%% true.

%% ?- wont_have_mice(john).
%% false.

%% ?- wont_have_mice(mammy).
%% true.

%% ?- may_have_mice(mammy).
%% false.
```

> - Light sleepers do not have anything which howls at night.

```
has(ryder, marshall).
has(ryder, rubble).
could_be_a_lightsleeper(X) :- has(X, Y) -> \+ howls_at_night(Y) ; true.
is_not_a_lightsleeper(X) :- has(X, Y), howls_at_night(Y).

%% ?- could_be_a_lightsleeper(max).
%% true.

%% ?- could_be_a_lightsleeper(ryder).
%% false.

%% ?- could_be_a_lightsleeper(Name).
%% Name = mammy.

%% ?- is_not_a_lightsleeper(max).
%% false.

%% ?- is_not_a_lightsleeper(mammy).
%% false.

%% ?- is_not_a_lightsleeper(max).
%% false.

%% ?- is_not_a_lightsleeper(Name).
%% Name = ryder.
```

> - John has either a cat or a hound.

```
has_cat_or_hound(X, Y) :- has(X, Y), (cat(Y) ; hound(Y)).
john_has(Y) :- cat(Y) ; hound(Y).
```